# Loading only properties from JSON into existing javascript object without destroying methods

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a object from a class that contains methods and properties like so:

```
function Fruit (type, color) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type;
    };
    this.loadJSON = function() {
        //TODO
    };
}

var red_apple = new Fruit ('apple', 'red');
```

I want to load new data from JSON like:

```
red_apple.loadJSON( '{"new_apple": {"color": "green", "type": "apple"}}' );
```

How would I implement `this.loadJSON`? Is there a standard function?

Comment: You can use [Object.extend](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=object%20extend)

Comment: Thanks, the duplicate (sorry for that) and Jonathan gave me the right keywords. I think I can figure it out now.

Comment: there is no such thing as Object.extend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery extend function

```
function Fruit (type, color) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type;
    };
    this.loadJSON = function(json) {
        //TODO
        var jsonFruit = JSON.parse(json);

        $.extend(this, jsonFruit.new_apple);
    };
}

var red_apple = new Fruit ('apple', 'red');

console.log(red_apple.getInfo()); // Prints "red apple"

red_apple.loadJSON( '{"new_apple": {"color": "green", "type": "apple"}}' );

console.log(red_apple.getInfo()); // Prints "green apple"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.loadJSON = function(json) {
    //TODO
    var jsonFruit = JSON.parse(json);

    this.color = jsonFruit.new_apple.color;
    this.type = jsonFruit.new_apple.type;
};
```

Comment: is that putting the values onto an existing object or creating a new object?

Comment: @brso05 He already has that method called `this.loadJSON` and needs just the implementation

Comment: @mshaaban is totally right. The problem was not about parsing a JSON string into an JSON object. I would've mentioned that.

Comment: @brso05 Question's title is `Loading only properties from JSON into existing javascript object **without destroying methods**`

Comment: Here's a function which will copy all variables that don't exist in the destination object. http://jsfiddle.net/76pmu4ou/